# android: Resend email verification to Parse user

Tags: android, parse-platform, email-validation

I am new learner to implement the Parse user data mgt. I would like to resend email verification. After researched, I got an answer that

"You can "update" the email field on their User object with the same current email value and save again. That will trigger a new verification email."

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can only modify the properties of a `ParseUser` for the one currently logged in for security reasons. Also don't forget to call one of the `save` methods on the user which your code is missing in your question.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
user.saveInBackground();
```

From the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-security)

> Specifically, you are not able to invoke any of the save or delete
>   type methods unless the ParseUser was obtained using an authenticated
>   method, like logIn or signUp. This ensures that only the user can
>   alter their own data.

So you don't need to "query" for the user as the user should already be logged in.

However, if you're doing this when a user is not logged in or globally, you may need to look at using cloud functions that allow administrative features.

For that you can refer to [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/user-administration-with-master-key) which refers to [cloud code](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code). I've never used that part of Parse so I can't help much there if that's what you need.

---

Just to add to this great answer.

If you're new to Android/Parse, it's a good opportunity to also learn how to do it "in the background - making the user wait". So that's **.saveInBackground**.

```
private void resendEmail()
  {
  ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
  user.setEmail(user.getEmail());

  ... here, bring up a message saying 'we're contacting the cloud!'

  user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
  {
  public void done(ParseException e)
    {
    ... here, get rid of that message

    if (e == null)
      {
      Utils.Log("resendEmail no problem.");

      ... here, bring up a message like...
      String un = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();
      "We have resent the validation email to " +un +". Please check your email!"
      }
    else
      {
      int errCodeSimple = e.getCode();
      Utils.Log(", some problem: " + errCodeSimple);

      ... here, bring up a message like...
      "We could not reach the internet! Try again later!"
      }
    }
  });

  }
```

Finally here's an amazing related trick in Android. When you create an account you'll want to check if it's a "valid-looking" email.  This takes 18,000 lines of code in iOS but only **one line of code** in Android.

```
maybeEmail = emailField.getText().toString();

if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(maybeEmail).matches())
  {
  userAlert("Please a valid email, buddy!!!");
  return;
  }
```

Hope it helps someone.